# LWC component on Screen flow returns case id, but not available for the Get Records next flow node instantly

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

LWC on Screen flow does return case id, but not available for the next flow node instantly
I have a screen flow where I have a LWC component as one of the nodes. The component calls an apex class to update case and then returns the case id. Just after the LWC screen flow node I have the Get Records element which uses the case id returned from the LWC screen component to get the actual case record. But what I find weird is that I don't see the case Id being available for the Get Records element. I did add a console.log statement to see if a case id is returned by the LWC component and I see it does. Is this because the apex class is being run asynchronously. Here is the snippet of the flow. The LWC component here is the Screen - Null Values.
[image]

Here is the apex code I have for the LWC component -

```
public without sharing class PopulateValuesForNullFieldsService {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String updateCaseFields(String caseId, String fieldsToUpdate) {
        Map<String, Object> fieldValues = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(fieldsToUpdate);
        
        Case caseToUpdate = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId];
        
        for(String fieldName : fieldValues.keySet()) {
            caseToUpdate.put(fieldName, fieldValues.get(fieldName));
        }      
        update caseToUpdate;

        // Return the case ID
        return caseId;
    }
}
```

Here is the LWC code making the call -

Meta file -

```
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
        <property name="caseId" label="Case Id"
            type="String"
            role="inputOnly" />
        <property name="fieldsWithNullValues" label="Fields With Null Values"
            type="String"
            role="inputOnly" />
        <property name="outputCaseId" label="Case Id"
            type="String"
            role="outputOnly" />
    </targetConfig>
```

Declaration in js file

```
@api outputCaseId;//
```

Called on the Next button click

```
if (allValid) {
            // Dispatch a FlowAttributeChangeEvent with the field values
            const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('fieldValues', fieldValues);
            this.dispatchEvent(attributeChangeEvent);

            updateCaseFields({ caseId: this.caseId, fieldsToUpdate: JSON.stringify(fieldValues) })
                .then(caseid => {
                    // Dispatch a FlowAttributeChangeEvent with the updated case ID
                    console.log('Result: ' + caseid);
                    const caseIdChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('outputCaseId', caseid);
                    this.dispatchEvent(caseIdChangeEvent);
                    console.log(caseIdChangeEvent);
                    console.log('Case ID: ' + this.outputCaseId);
                    
                    const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
                    this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error updating case fields: ', error);
                });
        } else {
            console.log('Please enter all required fields.')
        }
```

I have noticed this console.log statement console.log('Case ID: ' + this.outputCaseId); logs undefined.

I also tried console logging this console.log(caseIdChangeEvent) and I do the see the actual case id value there, here is the snip -

[image]

**UPDATE - After trying out Phil.W answer-**

Hello Phil.W,

Here is my updated code -

```
_outputCaseId;
@api
get outputCaseId() {
    return this._outputCaseId;
}

set outputCaseId(value) {
    this._outputCaseId = value;
}
```

This is what I am doing in the button click -

```
updateCaseFields({ caseId: this.caseId, fieldsToUpdate: JSON.stringify(fieldValues) })
                .then(caseId => {
                    // Dispatch a FlowAttributeChangeEvent with the updated case ID
                    this._outputCaseId = caseId;
                    console.log('Updated Case ID: ' + caseId);
                    this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('outputCaseId', caseId));
                    console.log('Output Case ID: ' + this.outputCaseId);

                    const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
                    this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
                })
```

Now as you mentioned I have a variable setup in flow to capture the value returned from LWC. I created an another screen element to print out the value returned by the LWC, next to the Screen - Null Values element. I still don't get the value returned to printed out on that screen.

**SECOND UPDATE**

The console.log statements do print out the expected values -

[image]

Here is how I am dispatching now -

```
updateCaseFields({ caseId: this.caseId, fieldsToUpdate: JSON.stringify(fieldValues) })
                .then(caseId => {
                    // Dispatch a FlowAttributeChangeEvent with the updated case ID
                    this._outputCaseId = caseId;
                    console.log('Updated Case ID: ' + caseId);
                    this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('outputCaseId', this.outputCaseId));
                    console.log('Output Case ID: ' + this.outputCaseId);

                    const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
                    this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
                })
```

This is what I see on my screen component to print out the values from LWC. The flow does not seem to receive it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up output API properties as getter/setter, as shown [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-props-getters-setters.html). An LWC is not allowed to change its own API properties directly, so here you have a private property behind the getter/setter which you can then change.

```js
_outputCaseId;

@api
get outputCaseId() {
  return this._outputCaseId;
}

set outputCaseId(value) {
  this._outputCaseId = value;
}
```

When notifying the flow you must first update the private property itself then fire the `FlowAttributeChangeEvent`. Both should have the same value, but anecdotally the flow engine gets the API property value rather than using the value in the event.

```js
updateCaseFields({ caseId: this.caseId, fieldsToUpdate: JSON.stringify(fieldValues) })
    .then(caseid => {
        this._outputCaseId = caseid;
        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('outputCaseId', caseid));
        ...
```

Clearly, the output property must be bound to a variable in the flow to allow the value to be obtained in the flow elements appearing after the screen element.

Comment: Hello Phil, I have added an update to the original post after trying out your code.

Comment: Have you looked at console logs from the imperative Apex promise `then` to verify the case ID gets back to the LWC correctly? If that is working, try ensuring the event is dispatched with `this.outputCaseId`. Also please [edit] to include the flow's variable declaration and show how you bound it to the LWC output property.

Comment: I have added the flows variable declaration to the post. Also added a second update. Mt flow is still not displaying the case id value.

Comment: Thank you Phil.W. I was able to figure it out. It was some extra js code that was in there doing all this trouble without conveying any error .